# Miller indices: How does one translates the orientation to the origin of the unit cell?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, miller-indices

In a section discussing **Miller indices**, my textbook says the following:

> The rules for determining the Miller indices of a direction or an orientation in a crystal are as follows: translate the orientation to the origin of the unit cell, and take the normalized coordinates of its other vertex.

What I'm confused about is how one translates the orientation to the origin of the unit cell?

Since the textbook just mentions this without elaboration or illustration, it is not clear precisely what this means or how one would go about it. I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain and demonstrate how this is (mathematically) done. Sources would be appreciated, if you have them.

Comment: When you reach a confusing point like this, consult another book or source. I usually found it beneficial  to read the same material from 2-3 books. Multiple sources gave me a better understanding of the topic being studied.

Comment: @MaxW I attempted to find clarification using a Google search before I posted this question. See the slide beginning *Determine the Miller indices for the plane*: https://www3.nd.edu/~amoukasi/CBE30361/Lecture__crystallography_B.pdf It's the same problem: The author mentions the process, but I don't see any explanation or illustration of how it is actually done.

Comment: try reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index

Comment: @MaxW I did, but there isn't even any mention of translations or "origin".

Comment: Just to clarify: It isn't the basics of Miller indices that I'm confused about, it's the specific aforementioned concept that I quoted from the textbook. I *did* attempt to research this myself before bothering people with the question.

Comment: Is it translation you don't understand? // Translation is a mathematical concept. Instead of x=0, y=0, and z=0 being the origin, you can translate the origin to a new point and create a new set of coordinates.  So If I want the origin at 1,2,3 the x'=x-1, y'=y-2, and z'=z-3. You can also rotate coordinates in all three axes.

Comment: @MaxW I'm familiar with the mathematical concept of translation. What I'm confused about is what is meant by "translating the orientation" to the origin of the unit cell. I understand the concept of an "origin of the unit cell". But what does it mean to "translate the orientation" to the origin of the unit cell (say, a simple cubic)?

Comment: @ThePointer Note that you may train yourself a bit, e.g. on https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/miller_indices/index.php

Comment: Don't focus too much on the paragraph that you cited, it's not the best description of how to find Miller indices. The word *orientation* there just means *direction*. To rephrase your textbook: if you start a vector in the origin of the unit cell, the Miller indices of the direction of this vector are the same as the coordinates of the vector's terminal point. Assuming that the vector ends on a lattice point so that the coordinates are integral. (not sure if my wording is clearer than the original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your structure contains a short piece of helical DNA, and it (the helix axis) starts at point P1 and goes to point P2. You want to know the Miller index associated with that direction. So you move the entire helix (without rotating) so that P1 is now at the origin. The new position of P2, lets call it P2(prime), will be at:

$$ P_2' = P_2 - P_1 $$

Just checking that is is a translation (I have to subtract the same vector from the entire structure, otherwise I'm rotating or warping it):

$$ P_1' = P_1 - P_1 = (0,0,0)$$

Again, the pair of two points still points in the same direction, but now $P_1$ is at the origin. Taking the fractional coordinates (i.e. along the unit cell axes) of $P_2'$, you can turn those into Miller indices $h$, $k$, and $l$ by multiplying with a large number and rounding to the next integer. Generally, the direction will be off because of the rounding. However, in special cases, e.g. if your DNA is on some crystallographic symmetry axis, the Miller indices will match your direction exactly.

Comment: Could you clarify "and you have a Miller index. *h*, *k*, and *l* will not typically be integers unless your DNA is on some crystallographic symmetry axis.". Miller indices, by definition, must be integers. The direction doesn't need to be a symmetry axis to have (integer) Miller indices.

Comment: @marcin I edited the answer. Here is an example: Let's say your fractional coordinates are (0.3147, 0.5324, 0.4143). Multiplying by 10000 tells me that the direction with Miller indices (3147, 5324, 4143) will point in just about the same direction (within sigfigs). You are unlikely to measure that reflection though. Multiplying by 32 gives (10.0704, 17.0368, 13.2576) so the Miller indices (10,17,13) have a similar direction to our direction of interest, and you might actually measure that reflection.